# Subquery max sequence number

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm hesitant to ask because I'm sure it's out there, but I just can't seem to come up with the keywords to find the answer. I'm stepping outside my boundaries by starting with subqueries (normally an Access user).

I have a query that has `TECH_ID`, `SEQ_NBR`, and `PELL_FT_AWD_AMT`

```
SELECT ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.SEQ_NBR
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT
GROUP BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.SEQ_NBR
HAVING (((ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR)="2013"))
ORDER BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID;
```

What I want to return is add a subquery that selects only the max `SEQ_NUM` for each record, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. In the past I would cheat and have a separate query that first gave me the `TECH_ID` and max `SEQ_NUM`, and then have a second query that use the original table and the first query in a join to get the rest.

How can I do this in one query?

Example:

```
TECH_ID    SEQ_NUM    PELL
1          1          4000
1          2          4000
1          3          5000
```

Using just the max of the sequence number still returns: `1; 2; 4000` and `1; 3; 5000` when I'm only wanting the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for, but it seems like this is all you need:

```
SELECT ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, MAX(ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.SEQ_NBR)
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT
GROUP BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT
HAVING (((ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR)="2013"))
ORDER BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID;
```

The two changes I made from your original query are adding `MAX()` around `SEQ_NBR` in the `SELECT` clause, and removing `SEQ_NBR` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

On an urelated note, you can make your queries shorter and easier to read by using [table aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). For example:

```
SELECT p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, MAX(p.SEQ_NBR)
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT p
GROUP BY p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT
HAVING (((p.AWD_YR)="2013"))
ORDER BY p.TECH_ID;
```

**Edit:** @Slippery Pete made the very good catch that your `HAVING` clause isn't valid. In general, when you want to filter results on a detailed level you use `WHERE`; if you want to filter results based on aggregate information then you use `HAVING`. In this case, you want a `WHERE`.

```
SELECT p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, MAX(p.SEQ_NBR)
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT p
WHERE  p.AWD_YR = "2013"
GROUP BY p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT
ORDER BY p.TECH_ID;
```

**Edit2:** I've read your comment below about `PELL` being different and wanting only rows with the highest sequence number per `TECH_ID`. You're actually asking a significantly more complicated question, which thus requires a significantly more complicated answer. Here is one possible SQL query to get what you want, though I do not know if MS Access supports these types of nested queries or not.

```
SELECT p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, p.SEQ_NBR
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT p
JOIN (
    SELECT TECH_ID, MAX(SEQ_NBR) AS 'SEQ_NBR'
    FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT
    GROUP BY TECH_ID
) AS m ON p.TECH_ID = m.TECH_ID AND p.SEQ_NBR = m.SEQ_NBR
WHERE p.AWD_YR = "2013"
ORDER BY p.TECH_ID;
```

Comment: And he doesn't even need table aliases because he's only pulling from one table. I would also change the `HAVING` to a `WHERE`, because he's not filtering on an aggregate (and remove those silly parenthesis around that predicate :P).

Comment: @bhamby Agreed on all accounts. I'm going to leave in the table aliases just for demonstration purposes, but you're right.

Comment: This is what I initially had, but it returns multiple results per `TECH_ID` due to the `PELL` field having different values. If a single `TECH_ID` has 8 sequence numbers, 1-3 having `4000` and 4-8 having `5000`, the results would return two results: 
`TECH_ID; 3; 4000` and 
`TECH_ID; 8; 5000`

I'm hoping to return just the latter due to having a higher sequence number.

Comment: @AndyLevesque See my latest edit. Your question is wandering into a new topic different than the original question, so if it gets more complicated I'd suggest posting a new question that focuses on the changes.

Answer (score 1):

That `having` clause didn't work for me either; I came up with this:

```
SELECT ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, max(ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.SEQ_NBR) as MAX_SEQ_NBR
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT
WHERE ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR = '2013'
GROUP BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.AWD_YR, ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT
ORDER BY ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT.TECH_ID;
```

Comment: Good catch on the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a correlated sub-query something like the following:

```
SELECT p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT, MAX(p.SEQ_NBR), (SELECT MAX(SEQ_NBR) FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT p2 
 WHERE p2.TECH_ID=p.TECH_ID AND p2.AWD_YR = 2013) AS MAX_SEQNBR
FROM ISRS_V_NEED_ANAL_RESULT_PARENT p
WHERE  p.AWD_YR = 2013
GROUP BY p.TECH_ID, p.AWD_YR, p.PELL_FT_AWD_AMT
ORDER BY p.TECH_ID

Here's an SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae484/7
```